# I can get follower_count, but what about FOLLOWING count for twitter users?

Tags: twitter

I can't find any explanation for this ANYWHERE.  Part of the value of a twitter account is a low following:follower ratio (at least it's correlated with high-profile twitter accounts).  But I can't seem to obtain the following count through the API.

Does anyone know why? Or if I'm missing something, where can I find info about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
friends_count, for list of friends you have which you are following.